# Word for tasks that don’t need attention

Tags: phrases, adjectives

Im looking for the word for doing a task, that can be done without giving a lot of attention to it. Your mind can do something else while doing the task.

The example was doing the dishes.

Comment: Please give a sentence leaving a blank where you would use this word. Why did you choose the tag "verbs"? It's confusing.

Comment: Mindless? Zombie task? On automatic? **Phoning it in**?

Comment: It’s fixed now. Looking for an adjective or phrase. Thank you for your answers

Comment: I just found the word I was looking for mundane. Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

"mindless" is the word that comes to my mind. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mindless)

> requiring little attention or thought
> *especially*: not intellectually challenging or stimulating